# Obtener datos de api en javascript mediante array

Tags: javascript, html

Este es el array que tengo, pero no logro obtener los datos desde la api(
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=3871336&units=metric&APPID=),  "main", "description"  en tiempo real, sin poner los datos en bruto en el codigo, asi como tengo el "main: vars.main" "description: vars.description", por consola me muestra undefined, los datos me los dan atraves de un json

```
const array =
                            [{
                                    weather: [
                                        {
                                            id: 803,
                                            main: vars.main,
                                            description: vars.description,
                                            icon: "04d"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ];
                    array.forEach(array => {
                        array.weather.forEach(infoWeather => {
                            console.log(infoWeather.main);
                            console.log(infoWeather.description);
                            $("#TextClima").val(infoWeather.main);
                            $("#TextClimaDescripcion").val(infoWeather.description);
                        });
                    });
```

Comment: La url que pusiste no deja acceder para ver los datos

Comment: No está el código del ajax o lo que fuera que usas

Comment: Pero tu codigo funciona, hice la prueba y me tra los datos del main y la description

Comment: @LukasBustos, colocaste tu key de la url, deberias eliminar ese comentario

Comment: si , pero lanza los datos en bruto, lo que quiero es que me lanze los datos desde la api en tiempo real

Comment: @LukasBustos que desde el api llegue el main y la description de una vez ? sin todo el array ? mejor dicho que en el Json que te retornan solo llegue `weather: [
                                        {
                                            id: 803,
                                            main: vars.main,
                                            description: vars.description,
                                            icon: "04d"
                                        }
                                    ]` esto ? asi

Comment: Me alegro que te haya funcionado mi solución Lukas, saludos.

Comment: Lo unico que tuve que cambiar fueron los 
.text(infoWeather.main); y .text(infoWeather.description);
por .val(infoWeather.main); y .val(infoWeather.description);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este sería un ejemplo usando `fetch`:

```
fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=3871336&units=metric&APPID=XXXXXX')
  .then((response)=>response.json())
  .then((jsonResponse)=>{
    jsonResponse.weather.forEach(infoWeather => {
      $("#TextClima").text(infoWeather.main);
      $("#TextClimaDescripcion").text(infoWeather.description);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto muchas gracias¡¡¡